# Array Keys Comparison With String Characters

Tags: php, comparison

I have a **string** and also have an **array** with two keys as following:

```
$string = "black"; // a string that has 5 characters 

$array = array(0=>"c", // an array that has two keys "c" and "b"
               1=>"b")
```

**Requirement:**

I need a loop that iterates and compares first key value of an array with all the characters of the string and then the second key value of the array with all the characters of a string.

If the key matches the character of a string, print the string character, else print a star (*). Something like this:

```
if($string[$character] == $array[$key]){

echo $string[$character];

      }
         else{
                echo "*";

                            }
//So in this case, Final Output should be:
// Final Output = b**c*
```

How can I approach to achieve the **Final Output**?

Comment: So you want to replace only the FIRST match with a *?

Comment: I want to replace every instance of the characters of the string with the key values, that is why I need a loop that can run until each key value goes through the string characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop the string and use `in_array()`:

```
$string = "black"; // a string that has 5 characters 
$array = array(0=>"c", // an array that has two keys "c" and "b"
               1=>"b");

for($i=0; $i<strlen($string); $i++){

    if(in_array($string[$i], $array)){
        echo $string[$i];
    } else {
        echo '*';
    }

}

// b**c*
```

[Codepad Example](http://codepad.org/Ii6wWSxf)

Comment: @Minhai you are awesome! works great.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late, but this would do the trick too:

```
$string = "black"; 
$array = array(0=>"c",
               1=>"b") ;

echo preg_replace("/[^". implode($array) ."]/", "*", $string);
```

Output: `b**c*`

Comment: And you are replacing the already known characters. It will result in `*la*k`